# Where can I find a list of daily builds?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

I'm interested in finding out which PPAs have daily builds associated with them so I can be sure I'm always running the latest software available by these teams. Does such a feature exist?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [PPA Manager](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager) by [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/). This is a graphical tool which lets you search, manage and browse through the database of PPA's on Launchpad. Searching it for the word "daily" should yeild many results.

I hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There was a full list of daily builds at https://code.launchpad.net/+daily-builds, but it appears to have been recently removed.